# What type of singularity does $\frac{e^{iaz}-e^{-z}}{z}$ have at $z=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

What type of singularity does $\frac{e^{iaz}-e^{-z}}{z}$ have at $z=0$? It is not a pole since the numerator is zero when $z=0$. The derivatives of this function always have a $z$ at the denominator, so we can't take the limit as $z\to 0$. Is it 
a removable singularity or an essential singularity? Why?

Comment: Don't think it has a singularity _atall_, unless I've made a bit of a blunder. It appears to me to have a perfectly welldefined limit at z=0: -1+ia .

Answer (score 1):

This is a removable singularity. This can be seen by the power series representation of this function. Using

$$e^z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}$$

we can deduce that

$$\frac{e^{iaz}-e^{-z}}{z}=\frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(iaz)^n-(-z)^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(ia)(iaz)^n+(-z)^n}{(n+1)!}$$

which is a continuous function. Thus, the singularity is removable.